# Port Forwarding so I can ssh to a virtual machine from outside the network

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

So I'm hosting a Linux Virtual Machine with VirtualBox , and I can connect to it trough ssh with putty from the host machine (so the port forwarding in the VirtuaBox settings is done correctly ) . what I need to do is connect thourgh ssh from outside the network , but I don't know how I should configure the port forwarding rule on my router settings in order for this to work.

[The Linux Virtual Machine ifconfig(i use the 192.168.56.101 ip to connect throguh putty:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4e5m.png)

[Settings that I tried on my router port forwarding rule:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnMkv.png)

Answer (score 0):

How you do this depends on how your virtual machine is set up.  If your virtual machine is on its own subnet, then the router needs to send traffic to the host machine, and the host machine must route the traffic when it receives it.  If your virtual machine acts like a device on the same subnet as one of the host machine's NICs, then you just send the traffic straight to the virtual machine's IP address.  Details on possible network configurations differ based on what virtual machine software you are using.

If the virtual machine is on its own subnet, make sure routing works well in *both* directions.  It is often easy to have traffic go from or to the virtual machine, while not having corresponding routing set up to make sure that traffic gets all the way back in the opposite direction.

NAT can simplify things.  It may be even more likely to complicate things.  (And, typically it has to be used if you're trying to access the public Internet when you're trying to use IPv4.)

Answer (score 0):

You could change the network adapter to *Bridged Adapter* or add another network interface of this type (which is actually what I have done with my VM on my laptop) if the one you are using needs to be NAT. That way, you can make a port forwarding in your router which addresses the VM directly because the VM becomes a new machine on your network.